# How can I rename files and subdirectories in a copied directory based on changes in the original?

Tags: unix, rsync

I have a directory structure with many hundreds of files and folders underneath it for organising files (in this case photos). I create backups of that directory structure by rsyncing it to identical copies on an external drives periodically. These drives may be offsite some of the time.

I want to restructure and rename the files and directories in the original and then, later, when I have an external drive onsite, be able to run some tool that will cause these structural and naming changes to happen on the backup. If I just us rsync, it'll have to recopy much of the data to the backup drive, which I'd rather avoid due to the sizes involved.

How can I get the changes I make to the original directory into the backups, as they become available, without having to recopy/rsync the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an incremental backup of a directory using hardlinks

```
rsync -a --delete --link-dest=../lastbackup $SRC $DEST_DIR/
```

Copy all files that exist in dir **B/**, but **NOT** in dir **../A/**, copy or merge to **C/**

```
rsync -v -r --checksum --compare-dest=../A/ B/ C/
```

Also, here is a good list of [backup software](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backup_Programs)